# Convergence in distribution plus convergence of moments.

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Suppose that the sequence of r.v $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ has all the moments, and $X_n\stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} X\sim N(0,\sigma)$. Assume that $E\{(X_n)^K\} \stackrel{n} {\longrightarrow} E(X^K)$, where $K\geq 1$ is an integer number. Can we say that $E\{(X_n)^{K+1}\} \stackrel{n}{\longrightarrow} E(X^{K+1})?$

Clarifications: The simbol $\stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow}$ represents convergence in Distribution.

Comment: I'm confused, why can't you plug in $K+1$ into the expression which says the moments converge? Or are you saying maybe that the even moments converge (as the normal distribution has odd moments equal to zero).

Comment: In this case, K is a fixed number. I mean, if we know that the convergence works with K=3 (for instance), can we say that it works with K=4?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general: take $X_n=X+Y_n$, where $\mathbb E[|Y_n|^K]\to 0$ but $\mathbb E[|Y_n|^{K +1}]=1$ for each $n$.